# TFS Build - Generate Website (no webproject)

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, build, web

I have many projects that I want to build using TFS Build. I have no problems with Windows Forms and WebForms PROJECTS.

But when I try to use TFS Build to build ASP.NET Website (the classic one), I have these problems:

1. I don't have any options to compile the project with Test Configuration (only Debug or Release).
2. I can't build an ASP.NET website because it's not a Web Project.

I want to know if there's a way to publish the website's precompiled files to the same shared location where I have my other projects.

Comment: FYI, web sites are not "the classic ones". They are a design flaw introduced with Visual Studio 2005 and corrected shortly thereafter in a service pack. I strongly recommend staying away from web site "projects". They are an aberration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might need a bit more detail here, or maybe I'm just clueless :-)

1. Test configuration - I'm assuming you've set up a Test build configuration?  If so, I'm not sure off the top of my head what's going on, but I've seen people forget to create the build configuration.
2. We've had no problem with our Websites, they get moved to build output or to wherever you specify in the Website properties pages
3. If you mean you want to use WebDeploy to publish, you're out of luck for the website - only web projects will do that.  But do a little team build customization, and you should be able to emulate that.

Not super satisfied with my answer, but hopefully I've pointed you towards something helpful...

Comment: I think you've got my idea but I didn't want to hear the third point. Talking with my coworkers I think we're going to migrate to web projects. Thanks for your answer =)

Comment: Yeah Web Projects are the shizzle, so good luck with that :-)